# Scala and integrated terminal in VS Code

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scala-repl

I am using the Scala REPL with the integrated terminal. I open the Scala REPL on the terminal and then send small snippets with

`workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText`

(which I have bound to a shortcut). This works fine when the snippets have to be run literally. But sometimes when definitions are mutually recursive, Scala requires that I start the code with the command

`scala> :paste`

and then finish with a ctrl+d. Is there a way that I can automatically wrap the selected text in a ":paste" + selected_text + "^d"?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

[`${selectedText}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) variable holds currently selected text, and [`sendSequence`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) supports variable substitution, hence in `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` try adding

```
[
    {
      "key": "cmd+shift+T",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": {
        "text": ":paste\u000D${selectedText}\u000D\u0004"
    }
]
```

where `\u0004` is `Control+D`, and `\u000D` is `Enter`. Now try

1. start `console` from sbt
2. select the source code you want to paste in `console`
3. Hit `cmd+shift+T`